How loud should I design my music? Not for personal opinion, but for other people listening in
If I am designing a music track for other people to listen in on, how loud (in decibels) should, say, a forte be?
A person shouldn't have to turn their volume up to 100 to hear it. On the other hand, he/she shouldn't have their ears blown out when their volume level isn't even that high.
What could be considered a reasonable level?

You should be using EBU R 128 to normalize your volume. Simply normalizing to peak decibels from full scale is not enough. If you can't use R 128 then it's pretty subjective, but I usually use -6dBFS peak. Some people use -3dBFS and some even go as high as -0.1dBFS.
You shouldn't just normalize to peak volume because it doesn't take into account the dynamic range of your audio, the duration of loud sounds (a balloon popping is louder than a jet engine but less dangerous), or the frequency of the audio (an inaudible sound at 18kHz could be painful at 2kHz).
Most audio mastering programs can do R 128 normalization. A CLI option is ffmpeg-normalize.

redbook. Nice, standard name ;) Welcome, man.

As quiet as possible; without influencing the noise floor of the audio.
There are a few options:

LUFS - This is a newer standard, which stands for "LU Full-scale." It measures perceptual loudness of the audio. Lots of modern music streaming services target "-14LUFS" (give-or-take) and will do post-processing to boost/attenuate your music to that level.
dBFS - Stands for "Decibel Full-scale," which measures the raw electrical signal of the audio, without regard for how loud it is perceptually.
EBU R 128 - As others have mentioned,  EBU R 128 is the international standard for recording. If you're targeting play on commercials, broadcasts, or other mediums besides music streaming services, go with this one and target to -23.

When normalizing/resampling audio, the dithering algorithm matters.
POW-r 1 is generally used for loud, compressed recordings. Dance music, club music, etc.
POW-r 2 is kind of a middle of the road.
POW-r 3 is used for classical recordings, or others with high dynamic range.
Remember, when converting an analog signal to digital, you're creating an approximation based on the sample rate and bit depth. Sample rate is how often a "snapshot" of the incoming signal is converted to 0's and 1's. Bit depth is the fidelity of the "snapshot."
This also occurs when resampling down, say from 32-bit to 24-bit, or 192,000 to 48,000Hz.
So say we have a digital audio file with 9 samples (created with a sample rate of n) and a bit-depth of 10 (noted by a-j).
j
i
h
g     -        
f   - -   -   
e   - -   -     -
d   - - - -     -
c   - - - -   - - 
b - - - - - - - - -  
a 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

The recorder has taken 9 samples when reading the input value of the electrical signal, and created these "buckets." Each - is going to represent 1 magnitude of gain, for argument's sake, so for bucket 1, the gain is 1. Bucket 2, the gain is 5, bucket 3 the gain is 6, and so forth.
These jumps decrease fidelity, so the dithering is smoothing the jump between these, and which algorithm you use matters, mathematically.
So after dithering, the lerp between buckets 2 and 3 would be 5.5, instead of the signal jumping in value from 5 to 6.
Please note: The target medium for your recordings can influence design decisions when creating audio for others. For example, if it's bass-heavy, less information will be able to be pressed to vinyl, so your Disc 1,2 split for sides A and B might not work.
The last time I checked, Spotify added non-neutral post-processing to recordings above -14 LUFS, but not if it had to bring the audio up to -14 LUFS.
Overall (and this is my opinion) is:
I wouldn't worry about the individual platform's colorations, just try and make it as quiet as possible, without affecting the noise floor, and without making it wildly different than other songs in that genre. If you mix your song too quietly, and someone turns up their stereo to hear your music, they might get blown out/damage their equipment (or worse: their hearing) when the next track from someone else comes on.
